# OS X alternatives to iTunes for playing FLAC

Tags: macos, software-rec, osx-lion, flac

I am new to OS X and their player iTunes doesn't seem to like FLAC (they support only ALAC). I am looking for a player to play FLACs.

I know VLC does the job, but is there any player that can:

1. Search media library
2. Manage playlists
3. Add favorites

I'm looking for something like Banshee in OS X.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's [**Clementine**](http://www.clementine-player.org/), a cross-platform fork of Amarok 1.4. I'm not sure how well (if at all) it works with iTunes playlists, etc. but it does support FLAC and has (in my opinion) a great library management feature set.

[image]

Comment: clementine looks fabulous

Comment: clementine IS awesome!

Comment: will FLAC 24bits be downsampled?

Comment: God, those scroll bars are hideous.

Comment: @Syzygy Those are Mac OS X scrollbars. Clementine uses the widgets of the platform it's running on.

Answer (score 2):

[**Enqueue**](http://www.enqueueapp.com/) does everything you want and the nice thing is that you can assign any folder or folders to it and it will watch them.

> **Extensive File Format Support**
>   Enqueue supports tagging and playback
>   for many formats including mp3, mp4, aac, ogg, flac, wav, aiff,
>   musepack and more.

[image]

I've only used the beta which wasn't completely stable, but it is out of beta now.

Comment: wow clementine looks nice. and it's free, whereas enqueue is a paid app now that it's out of beta.

Comment: Just a note, i bought (It's not free!) it believing it was under active development - that is not the case, it's been unchanged since january 2012. Reference: http://www.enqueueapp.com/changelog.html

Answer (score 1):

VLC media player is pretty good for flac; and also i think double-twist has flac support, but im not shure (personally, i prefer studio quality AAC). with VLC you cannot sync any devices (as far as i know), but the good thing about double-twist is... well, it has syncing support for both android devices and iPods (excluding iPod touch 3). also, double-twist has playlist and smart-playlist support, as well as favorites, a rating system, a music store, a genius-like feature, and so many other features that expand on the ones iTunes has.